# How to simplify this code？

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, concurrency

I test concurrency in my program and write the following code

```
vector<unique_ptr<future<double>>> results;
for (unsigned i = 0; i != 16; ++i)
{
     unique_ptr <future<double>> result(new future<double >{ async(once) });
     results.push_back(move(result));
}
auto ave = (results[0]->get() + results[1]->get() + results[2]->get() +\
    results[3]->get() + results[4]->get() + results[5]->get() +\
    results[6]->get() + results[7]->get() + results[8]->get() + \
    results[9]->get() + results[10]->get() + results[11]->get() + \
    results[12]->get() + results[13]->get() + results[14]->get() + \
    results[15]->get()) / 16.0;
```

once is a function which takes no parameter and returns a double, for instance, return a random number in [0,1]. The ave average the 16 results. I find the code is really redundant what if I average for 100 times. Use a loop maybe solve the problem but I'm not sure whether the concurrency is still working, so I wander how to simplify the code?

Comment: No need for backslashes at the end of the line.

Comment: If you want a code-review, [there's a site for that](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is there any reason you allocate the `std::future`s dynamically?

Comment: You can use `vector<future<double>> results;` and `results.push_back(async(once));` without `unique_ptr`. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WhoOazlTs8jfR4Dl

Comment: i know the `future<double> type` cannot be copied, but the element in the vector   should be `copyable` . So I use `unique_ptr `rather than the elements itself. I am really confused that why your code can work?

Comment: `unique_ptr` is also *non-copyable* type as same as `future`, but both types are *movable*. And `vector` container does not require copyable for its element type in C++11.

Answer (score 10):

Learn the [C++ algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm):

```
using type = unique_ptr<future<double>>;
auto mean = std::accumulate(results.begin(), results.end(), 0.0,
        [](double a, type const& b) { return a + b->get(); }) / results.length();
```

Comment: (Judging by my rush to publish the wrong answer, apparently *I* should learn the C++ algorithms as well, before posting here … I’ve corrected that now)

Comment: @UmNyobe It actually does, the default operation for `std::accumulate` is `std::plus`, i.e. summation. However, that obviously isn’t specialised for elements of `unique_ptr<future<T>>` (it *could* conceivable be specialised for that).

Answer (score 1):

C++ algorithms is the way to go, as Konrad Rudolph pointed out. This answer is only an extension if algorithms cannot be used for whatever reason. Without algorithms, you could use another for loop. This monstrous block of code

```
auto ave = (results[0]->get()  + results[1]->get()  + results[2]->get()  +
            results[3]->get()  + results[4]->get()  + results[5]->get()  +
            results[6]->get()  + results[7]->get()  + results[8]->get()  +
            results[9]->get()  + results[10]->get() + results[11]->get() +
            results[12]->get() + results[13]->get() + results[14]->get() +
            results[15]->get()) / 16.0;
```

could be replaced by

```
auto it = results.begin();
auto ave = (*(it++))->get(); // so you can still use auto
for(/* it already initialized */; it != results.end(); ++it)
    ave += (*it)->get();
ave /= results.size();
```

which will work for any number of elements in your `vector`.

Comment: I know the loop do the work. In the expression 'auto accum = results[0]->get() +  results[1]->get()', results[0]->get() and results[1]->get() run concurrently. But if the accumulated sum is calculated in a loop manner, I wander whether concurrency is still working ?

Comment: How to enable them run concurrently?

Comment: If you want your reduce operation (summation of elements) to run concurrently, you need to split the problem into logical parts. E.g. you could concurrently add two neighboring values to reduce your 16 values to 8 values, and repeat this step until you're left with one value. To achieve concurrency, you could use threads or SSE instructions.